# Combining two-part SQL query into one query

Tags: sql, join, performance

I have a SQL query that I'm currently solving by doing two queries.  I am wondering if there is a way to do it in a single query that makes it more efficient.

Consider two tables:

Transaction_Entries table and Transactions, each one defined below:

```
Transactions
- id
- reference_number  (varchar)


Transaction_Entries
- id
- account_id
- transaction_id (references Transactions table)
```

Notes: There are multiple transaction entries per transaction.  Some transactions are related, and will have the same reference_number string.

To get all transaction entries for Account X, then I would do

```
SELECT E.*, T.reference_number, sum(debit_value) total 
  FROM Transaction_Entries E 
  JOIN Transactions T ON (E.transaction_id=T.id) 
 where E.account_id = X
```

The next part is the hard part. I want to find all related transactions, regardless of the account id.   First I make a list of all the unique reference numbers I found in the previous result set.  Then for each one, I can query all the transactions that have that reference number.  Assume that I hold all the rows from the previous query in `PreviousResultSet`

```
UniqueReferenceNumbers = GetUniqueReferenceNumbers(PreviousResultSet) // in Java
foreach R in UniqueReferenceNumbers // in Java
     SELECT *, sum(debit_value) total 
       FROM Transaction_Entries 
       where transaction_id IN (SELECT * 
                                 FROM Transactions 
                                WHERE reference_number=R)
       AND account_id = X
       GROUP BY another_field
```

Any suggestions how I can put this into a single efficient query?

NOTE:  I have edited the original question. The new addition is the fact that when I do the second query, I am only looking for Transaction Entries that match the reference_number AND have the same account Id.  Also, I am trying to group by another_field and sum the debit_values according to that grouping.

What I am finding when trying to use the solution below provided by @Gratzy is that duplicate rows are being returned and so the sum(debit_value) is always twice the value it should be.  I think it's because there are other Transaction_Entries in there that don't match the account_id but that match the join criteria.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT distinct E2.*, T.reference_number 
FROM Transaction_Entries E 
INNER JOIN Transactions T ON (E.transaction_id=T.id) 
INNER JOIN Transactions T2 on T.reference_number = T2.reference_number
INNER JOIN Transaction_Entries E2 on T2.id = E2.transaction_Id
where E.account_id = X
```

If the account has numerous transaction_Entries for the same reference_number you may get duplicates

**EDIT** Added @van's suggestion I believe he is correct, thank you.

**EDIT**
This is edited to limit to the same account_id's

```
SELECT distinct E2.*, T.reference_number  
FROM Transaction_Entries E  
INNER JOIN Transactions T ON (E.transaction_id=T.id)  
INNER JOIN Transactions T2 on T.reference_number = T2.reference_number 
INNER JOIN Transaction_Entries E2 on T2.id = E2.transaction_Id and E2.account_id = E.account_id
where E.account_id = x
```

Comment: I think that will limit it to only entries that share the same account_id.  He mentioned that it should include all transactions with the same reference number, regardless of the account id.

Comment: On a test table I made with 7 Transaction_Entries your query returns a result set with 8 rows. This seems very surprising to me. Is it supposed to be possible to return more rows than exist, or do you have an error in your query? I can post the test table if you need.

Comment: @Eric Petroelje no I don't think so but it may result it duplicate rows

Comment: @Mark Byers the original row probably got returned twice, like I said this may result in duplicates can wrap another select distinct around it.

Comment: Replace your `SELECT` with `SELECT DISTINCT E2.*` and you have got yourself the exact answer.

Comment: Hello all.  Thanks for the responses.  I left out some details in hopes to simplify the problem, but those details now seem to be important.  The solution you give *almost* works.   I have edited my original post to include the additional information.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think this would work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Transaction_Entries te
INNER JOIN Transactions t ON t.id = te.transaction_id
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT T.reference_number 
  FROM Transaction_Entries E 
  JOIN Transactions T ON (E.transaction_id=T.id) 
  WHERE E.account_id = X
) refs ON t.reference_number = refs.reference_number
```

Answer (score 0):

why not:

```
select *
from   Transaction_Entries
where  transaction_id In (select   id, 
                          from     transactions 
                          group by reference_number)
```